# Is there a better way of moving elements in a vector

Tags: c++, vector, move, stdvector, swap

I have a std::vector of elements and would like to move an element to a specified position.
I already have a solution, but I'm courious, if there is a better way to do so.

Let'ts assume I'd like to move the last element to the index pos;

I could do a

```
auto posToInsert = vecElements.begin();
std::advance(posToInsert, pos);
vecElements.insert(posToInsert, *m_vecRows.rbegin());
vecElements.erase(m_vecRows.rbegin());
```

but this will reallocate memory.

Sadly a

```
std::move(vecElements.rbegin(), vecElements.rbegin(), posToInsert);
```

doesn't do the trick.

My current solution does some swaps, but no new memory allocation

```
auto newElement = vecElements.rbegin();
for (auto currentPos = vecElements.size()-1; currentPos != pos; --currentPos)
    newElement->swap(*(newElement + 1)); // reverseIterator +1 = element before
```

To clarify it, because @NathanOliver asked ... the remaining ordering of the vector should be preserved.

Is there a better way of doing it?

Comment: Do you care about the element that is the the position you want to move to?  If not, just swap them

Comment: Added a clarification to the text ... the ordering of the other elements should remain untouched.

Comment: Try -- Get the value at the source positon, erase the element at the source positon, then insert that value at the destination position.

Comment: *but this will reallocate memory* -- How many elements are we dealing with?  What is the issue with reallocation occurring?  Usually, the vector implements a strategy where the amount of times a reallocation is done is minimized.  It isn't as if every time an element is added, a reallocation is done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [`std::rotate`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/rotate):

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> values{1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
    std::rotate(values.begin()+2, values.end()-1, values.end());
    for(int i: values)
        std::cout << i << " ";
    std::cout << "\n";
}
```

[try it](https://godbolt.org/z/ZJKzyE)

Outputs:
`1 2 5 3 4`

You can probably adjust the iterators used if you need to move an element that isn't at the end.

Comment: Thanks, I forgot the rotate ... and a deep bow to Sean Parent

Answer (score 0):

Move the element out of the vector, erase the element, then insert.  This is guaranteed to not reallocate as that only happens when `size() > capcity()` and that can't happen here because erasing first guarantees that `size() <= capcity() - 1`

In the case of moving the last element, that would look like

```
auto temp = std::move(vecElements.back())
vecElements.erase(vecElements.rbegin());
vecElements.insert(posToInsert, std::move(temp));
```

So, this cost you two moves and no reallocation.